# How can I create a js/Notification in ClojureScript that can focus on the window?

Tags: clojure, notifications, focus, clojurescript

I want to create a (chrome) Notification with text, and I can click on the notification to be taken to the page that issued the notification. Here's the closest I've gotten, and notice it's very much non-idiomatic. I had to use `js*` (js star) which, I can't find docs for, but it just executes a string of javascript.

```
(js* "  var notification = new Notification('Here is the title', {
    icon: 'http://path.to/my/icon.png',
    body: 'Some body text',
  });

  notification.onclick = function () {
    console.log('hi there');
    this.close();
    window.focus();
  };")
```

Notice, the `log` works, the `close` works, but the `window.focus()` does not. If you copy and past the js portion of this code into your browser's console, it *does* work.

I think the correct answer should look more like the following, but the `onclick` doesn't work at all, for any function:

```
(new js/Notification "Here is the title"
             (clj->js {:body "(click to vist page)"
                       :onclick #(.focus js/window)}))
```

**EDIT**: if you type in the following (say, in figwheel), `js/window` definitely has a `focus` param. Obvious, but I just checked, but it doesn't work when called with `(.focus js/window)`:

```
(.keys js/Object js/window)
```

This doesn't even work to focus:

```
(js* "window.focus()")
```

And I can't seem to find any keys attached to `js/Notification` to get `onclick` working:

```
(.keys js/Object (new js/Notification "hi" (clj->js {:body "body text"})))
```

I must be doing something wrong, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a "straight port" of your original JavaScript code:

```clj
(let [title "Here is the title"
      js-opts (js-obj "icon" "http://path.to/my/icon.png"
                      "body" "Some body text")
      js-notification (js/Notification. title js-opts)]
  (aset js-notification "onclick"
    (fn []
      (this-as js-this
        (.log js/console "hi there")
        (.close js-this)
        (.focus js/window)))))
```

Notice I prefixed JavaScript references with `js-`, which is a common convention when dealing with JavaScript interop in ClojureScript.

Comment: Sweet! `onclick` totally works! Thank you thank you! 

Hm, the `(.focus js/window)` doesn't seem to work though, any idea why `window.focus()` works (in js) but not the cljs?